# PHP multiple times calling recursive function with static variable returns incorrect data

Tags: php, variables, static

I have function that returns count of elements:

```
<?
function get_path($node, $check=null) { 

static $count;

$result = mysql_query('SELECT NAME, PARENT_ID FROM b_disk_object  
                       WHERE ID="'.$node.'";'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

    if ($row['NAME']!='') { 
            $path=$row['NAME'];

            if($path==$check){
                $count++;
                $path=get_path($row['PARENT_ID'],$check);
            }

    $path=get_path($row['PARENT_ID'],$check);
    }
return $count;

} ?>
```

This works fine when I call the function once, but if I call it more than one time it returns incorrect data - it adds to count result from previous function call. For example when I call it for the first time it returns 5, when I call it once more, instead of returning 2, it returns 7.

```
ID         NAME                        PARENT_ID 
1         Sales                             
2         Marketing                      1
3         sales_optimiztaion.txt         2
4         Quotes                         6
5         list.xls                       4
6         General data   
7         file.odt                       1
```

I want to count how many files doe's, for example, Sales folder contain - in this case - 2( sales_optimiztaion.txt  and file.odt  ).

Comment: Static variables keep their value from the previous call, that's the whole point. So each time you call the function, it adds to it. Why do you expect something different?

Comment: Why static count? Just make it a regular variable. Also you should minimise the number of SQL queries within loops (or recursive functions in this case) if possible, it won't do any favours for your performance

Comment: But if I use usual variable, function doe's not work

Comment: Actually, it sounds like *using* a static variable doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want `$count` to be reset to `0` when you call the function from outside, but keep its value when you make recursive calls. But static variables don't distinguish where the function was called from, they always keep their value from the previous call.

Instead of a static variable, use a function parameter with a default value.

```
function get_path($node, $check=null, $count = 0) { 

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT NAME, PARENT_ID FROM b_disk_object  
                           WHERE ID="'.$node.'";'); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

    if ($row['NAME']!='') { 
        $path=$row['NAME'];

        if($path==$check){
            $count++;
            $count = get_path($row['PARENT_ID'],$check, $count);
        }

        $count = get_path($row['PARENT_ID'], $check, $count);
    }
    return $count;
}
```

I think you can write this with a simple loop instead of recursion:

```
function get_path($node, $check = null) {
    $count = 0;
    while (true) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT NAME, PARENT_ID
                                FROM b_disk_object
                                WHERE ID = '$node'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if (!$row) { // Reached the end of the parent chain
            return $count;
        }
        if ($row['NAME'] == $check) {
            $count++;
        }
        $node = $row['PARENT_ID'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little unsure about the rest of the logic. Why do you make the recursive call twice? First after checking if `$path == $check`, and then outside the `if`.

Comment: if($path==$check) cycle runs exactly how many times it should run. Each time when if cycle is true it sets $count to 1, instead of adding it and function doe's not return the result. And you are right, I don't need to make call twice

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this recursively? It seems like it could just be a simple loop.

Comment: I have hierarchial data in my database, so I must loop through its structure

Comment: No it doe's not work, again if ($row['NAME'] == $check) runs exactly how many times it should run, so it works fine, but function doe's not return correct value

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the correct value that should be returned? I obviously don't understand what you're trying to count.

Comment: I upgraded my question

Comment: I think your SQL query is backwards. You should be looking for rows `WHERE PARENT_ID = $node`, then recursing into them.

Comment: Maybe, but anyway for the first time with global variable it works fine

Comment: If that works, then do it that way. Instead of a static variable, use a global variable. And then set it to `0` before you call the function.

Comment: Not the best way, but it should work, Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use regular variable as other pointed out. Set the initial value to 0. The code looks good; is basic; I can't imagine why it would not work. What does not work? Have you traced your program? Tracing would reveal the source of the problem to you.

Use a paradigm something like this

```
       if($path==$check){
            $count++;
            $count = $count + get_path($row['PARENT_ID'],$check);
        }
```

Comment: I can't do it inside of the function, because it recursive, and each time function runs it sets the variable to 0 again and again

Comment: Why can't? Use something like this

    $count++;
    $count = $count + get_path($row['PARENT_ID'],$check);

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late answer.
You can add a flag for when you call the function from outside or inside like this and reset your variable:

```
<?
function get_path($node, $check=null, $reset=true) { 

static $count;

if ($reset)
    $count = 0;

$result = mysql_query('SELECT NAME, PARENT_ID FROM b_disk_object  
                       WHERE ID="'.$node.'";'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

    if ($row['NAME']!='') { 
            $path=$row['NAME'];

            if($path==$check){
                $count++;
                $path=get_path($row['PARENT_ID'],$check, false); //do not reset
            }

    $path=get_path($row['PARENT_ID'],$check, false); //do not reset
    }
return $count;

} ?>
```